# Programatically setting default Geodatabase and Workspaces for map document?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, configuration

I have a QC process that has a bunch of models that need to be sequentially run, and then the results manually inspected between each model.

I know how to manually set the default GDB for the Map Document (`File-->Map Document Properties-->Default Geodatabase`).

I also know how to manually set the default Geoprocessing Workspaces (`Geoprocessing-->Environments-->Workspace`).

I already have a "setup script" that generate a GDB, Feature Datasets, define the spatial reference, etc, and I would like to be able to integrate these steps into the setup procedure as well.

Can these settings be automatically set?  For example, I have tried `arcpy.env.workspace`, but that only appears to work within a script, not setting it at the "application" level.  Is this possible?

I know it seems like a small thing, but I have many "areas of interest" that we have to look at, and each one gets placed in its own MXD and GDB (so yes, I could do it by hand... over & over again).

Comment: You may have to use ArcObjects to do this.  I know in VBA there is a on document open event that could fire when your mxd is opened (with the understanding that you use this VBA map doc as a template and push your data into it with your model/script).  You could store your various env settings within a different xml files which would get called based on your mxd name or a common path of the layers within the map doc.  Then, you could set wks by using the gp.SetEnvironmentValue method (see link http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001n5000000).

Answer (score 2):

Building upon what @artwork21 mentioned, below is the VBA code that you would put into the normal template section:

```vb
Private Function MxDocument_OpenDocument() As Boolean
    Dim pWorkspaceName As IWorkspaceName
    Set pWorkspaceName = New WorkspaceName
    pWorkspaceName.WorkspaceFactoryProgID = "esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory"
    pWorkspaceName.PathName = "C:\Scratch\MyDefaultGDB.gdb"
    Dim pGxCatalogDefaultDatabase As IGxCatalogDefaultDatabase
    Set pGxCatalogDefaultDatabase = Application
    pGxCatalogDefaultDatabase.DefaultDatabaseName = pWorkspaceName
End Function
```

This code assumes you are setting the default geodatabase to be a file geodatabase and in this example it is called *C:\Scratch\MyDefaultGDB.gdb*. Placing this code into the Normal template section means that the code will be executed every time an MXD is opened.

Comment: Thank you Hornbydd. Folded into https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/308273/108