# Setting default gdb from ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, workspace

I created a new gdb by

```
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management('e:/Rstack', 'new.gdb')
arcpy.env.workspace = 'e:/Rstack/new.gdb'
```

But how to set this new gdb as my default gdb by arcpy, without opening ArcGIS desktop? Setting env workspace does not seem to work here.

Comment: Related? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71207/how-to-programatically-set-default-geodatabase-and-workspaces-for-a-map-document

Comment: Related discussion on Geonet which gives a clear use case for when/where/why this is wanted: [Default .gdb in Map Document Properties: Using arcpy to change it](https://community.esri.com/thread/163044). No solutions (yet)

Answer (score 4):

This took a bit of digging, but it annoyed me enough this morning to dig almost all the way down. Unfortunately I didn't find an accessible solution for v10 arcpy, however in Pro it's available out of the box as `arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject().defaultGeodatabase`

#### python ArcGIS Pro

```py
    import arcpy
    aprx_path = r'X:\Projects\2019\ENV.533.aprx'
    gdb_path = r'X:\shared\ENV_default.gdb'

    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprx_path) # or 'CURRENT' in live py console
    aprx.defaultGeodatabase = gdb_path
    del arcpy.env.workspace # Optional, ensure default gdb used in rest of this script
```

*From https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm*

#### python ArcMap 10

```py
    # Not real code! waiting/digging for solution
    import arcpy.mapping.convertArcObjectToPythonObject as convert
    defgdb = convert('IGxCatalogDefaultDatabase')
    defgdb.DefaultDatabaseName = r"D:\path\to\default.gdb"
```

*From <`http://your.kudos.link/here`>*

#### C# ArcGIS Pro

```cs
    //Create an empty project. The project will be created in the default folder
    //It will be named MyProject1, MyProject2, or similar...
    await Project.CreateAsync();
    //Gets the current project
    var project = Project.Current;
    //Get default gdb path
    var projGDBPath = Project.Current.DefaultGeodatabasePath;
```

*From https://github.com/esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProSnippets-content#get-the-projects-default-gdb-path*

#### .NET ArcMap 10

```cs
    IWorkspaceName name = new WorkspaceNameClass();
    name.WorkspaceFactoryProgID = "esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory";
    name.PathName = @"E:\Projects\WorldSoil\ProjectData.gdb";
    IGxCatalogDefaultDatabase gdb = app as IGxCatalogDefaultDatabase;
    gdb.DefaultDatabaseName = name;
```

*From http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGxCatalogDefaultDatabase_Interface/0014000000qw000000/*

#### VBA ArcMap 10

```vb
    Private Function MxDocument_OpenDocument() As Boolean
    Dim pWorkspaceName As IWorkspaceName
    Set pWorkspaceName = New WorkspaceName
    pWorkspaceName.WorkspaceFactoryProgID = "esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory"
    pWorkspaceName.PathName = "C:\Scratch\MyDefaultGDB.gdb"
    Dim pGxCatalogDefaultDatabase As IGxCatalogDefaultDatabase
    Set pGxCatalogDefaultDatabase = Application
    pGxCatalogDefaultDatabase.DefaultDatabaseName = pWorkspaceName
    End Function
```

Placing this code into the Normal template section means that the code will be executed every time an MXD is opened.

*From https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/192717/108*

Comment: Some good diggin'! I like seeing how to achieve the same thing, setting the default database, across the different ArcGIS environments.

Answer (score 0):

[How To: Set the default Home folder and geodatabase location for new map documents](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011581):

> Instructions provided describe how to create and update a registry
>   string value used to override the default location of the Home folder
>   for new documents. This process involves editing the system registry.

and

> Alternatively, a sample toolbox is available on arcgis.com containing
>   a single script tool.

Comment: -1 because things have changed. It was the best answer available a few years ago as there were no arcpy options but that's changed and it's now off topic (non-code answer to a "looking for a code method" question)